# ldap error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090D14, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation

Tags: ldap

I am trying to add values in AD group via apache DS using ldif import
it gives me error as

```
#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://ad.abc.com:389
#!DATE 2015-11-20T15:29:11.041
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 16 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C090D14, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v23f0 ]
dn: CN=I_abc,OU=xyz,OU=Groups,DC=ad,DC=abc,DC=com
changetype: add
add: uniqueMember
uniqueMember: CN=xyz,DC=ad,DC=abc,DC=com
```

Comment: You should provide more information. An example of your LDIF file and some more information ont he Group you are trying to add the user to. But you maybe looking for "member" and not "uniqueMember"

Comment: adding member helped.. Thanks a ton !!

Comment: You could answer your own question, so it help others.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information. An example of your LDIF file and some more information ont he Group you are trying to add the user to. But you maybe looking for "member" and not "uniqueMember"